# ¿Cómo crear un programa en C que en caso de no ingresarle ningún número devuelva un número por default?

Tags: c, variables-globales, menu, integer, numero

Elabora un programa que muestre el siguiente menú:
▪ Ingresa un número
▪ Incrementa un número
▪ Decrementa un número
▪ Salir

Cada una de las opciones del menú llamará a una función que realizará una tarea específica, como se indica a continuación:

▪ La opción 1 aceptará el ingreso de un número entero; si no se ocupa esta opción, se iniciará con el número 10.

▪ La opción 2 le sumará un 1 al número anterior; y la opción 3 le restará un 1 al número mencionado. Utiliza variables globales.

Y este es el programa que llevo:

/* Programa: Incremento y decremento de un número */

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, resta, suma;

      printf( "\n   Introduzca un numero (entero): " );
      scanf( "%d", &n );

    
    suma = n + 1;
    resta = n - 1;

    printf( "\n   La suma es: %d", suma );
    printf( "\n\n   La resta es: %d", resta);

    getch(); /* Pausa */

    return 0;
}
```

/* El detalle es que ya pude hacer que el programa me sume y me reste un 1 pero no he encontrado la forma de darle una instrucción para que en caso de no ingresar un número de por default el número 10. Espero de favor me den algún tip.*/

Comment: Según la documentación de [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), el valor de retorno de la función es el número de asignaciones correctas. Piénsalo y crea un [mre] mostrando que intentaste.

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo el enunciado, has de mostrar un menú de selección, la primera opción te pedirá un numero el cual se asignará a la variable global, la cual por defecto es 10, y dos funciones extra por separado que permiten incrementar en 1 el número y otra que decremente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Variable global solicitada
int numero = 10;

// Funciones específicas
void ingresarNumero() {
    printf("Ingresa un número: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &numero) != 1) {
        // Limpiar el búfer de entrada en caso de entrada no válida
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Entrada no válida. Se utilizará el valor actual(%d)\n", numero);
}
}

void incrementarNumero() {
    printf("Número incrementado: %d\n", ++numero);
}

void decrementarNumero() {
    printf("Número decrementado: %d\n", --numero);
}

int main() {
    int opcion;

    do {
        // Mostrar el menú
        printf("\nMenú:\n");
        printf("1. Ingresa un número\n");
        printf("2. Incrementa un número\n");
        printf("3. Decrementa un número\n");
        printf("Selecciona una opción: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &opcion) != 1) {
            // Limpiar el búfer de entrada en caso de entrada no válida
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            printf("Entrada no válida. Inténtalo de nuevo.\n");
        continue;
    }

        // Realizar la tarea correspondiente según la opción seleccionada
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                ingresarNumero();
                break;
            case 2:
                incrementarNumero();
                break;
            case 3:
                decrementarNumero();
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opción no válida. Inténtalo de nuevo.\n");
        }

    } while (opcion != 2 && opcion != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

La premisa es que el número lo almacenes en una variable global, al ejecutar el programa se pedirá cual de las opciones se quiere, en caso de pedir introducir un numero, llamamos a la función correspondiente la cual solicita introducir un numero y lo guarda en la variable global, por último las siguientes opciones mostrarán el incremento y decremento de dicho número. Por otro lado para evitar problemas de entrada, se comprueba el resultado de scanf para asegurar que la entrada ha sido correcta, en caso de un valor no válido, se limpia el buffer para prevenir bucle infinito en el while.

Comment: Recuerda que aquí dejamos que se esfuercen antes de responder.

Comment: La pregunta fue formulada el 3 de noviembre y nadie ha dado una respuesta, creo que es tiempo suficiente para que alguien se esfuerce. Mejor ayudar a alguien que pueda tener un problema similar :)